# What kind of runtime behavior should we expect of Finite Element Methods?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, experimental-analysis

For a typical finite element algorithms, what kind of order of growth in solution time (i.e solve stiffness matrix & post-processing) are we expected to see with an increase in number of elements?

Literature I have seen show exponential and power-law like behavior when comparing solve time to number of elements even when viewed on a log-log scale.

I ask this question as I have ran some analysis and plot the solution time vs number of elements, and it is not what I have expected, as it depicts almost linear behavior (loglog scale). Seen below:

[image: SolveTimevsNumOfElements]

This was the case for both parallel and serial processing.

Does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: "even when viewed on a log-log scale" -- Do you mean one axis is $\log \log x$ and the other $y$, or that both are $\log x$? Because you are doing the latter, and then linear plot means linear growth.

Comment: I removed your tech specs as they should be irrelevant. Notes: 1) A plot based on a finite sample need not fit an asymptotic (it may just be that $n_0$ is larger than what you've tried). 2) Literature will probably give *worst*-case results; what kind of instances are you running here?

Comment: Thank you Raphael. 
Both axis are log x, it is a simple bi-linear elastic-plastic analysis with one step done on Abaqus Standard.

Comment: @Raphael Does anyone use "log-log scale" to mean anything other than "plot the log of one quantity vs the log of the other"?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I have no idea, to be honest. I was being confused about what the OP expected to see.